# Connectedness of X

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Prove that metric space X is connected if and only if for every two points in X, there is a connected subset of X which contains both.

$(=>)$ trivial for $X$ and $ø$. How should I proceed about any proper, non-empty subset $A$ of $X$ that contains both the points?

Also, I am not sure how to go about the other direction (<=) either.

Comment: For the other direction proceed by contradiction. Forward: just use $X$ itself.

Comment: Why would you look for a proper subset of $X$ in $\Rightarrow$, or even make a case for subsets at all?

Comment: Not in <= direction. I am just looking for a proper subset in =>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

($=>$)
$X$ itself is a subset of $X$--it doesn't need to be proper.

($<=$)
Assume $X$ isn't connected. Let $c(X)$ be the set of connected components in $X$. Then, since $X$ not connected, there exists $c_1, c_2\in c(X)$ s.t. $c_1\neq c_2$. Let $p\in c_1$, $q\in c_2$. But, there exists a connected set containing $p, q$. Thus, $p,q$ are in the same component of $X$. This is obviously a contradiction, so, indeed, $X$ is connected.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove the <= part directly if you remember that the union of connected sets which have a common point is connected. Fix the first point and let the second roam around the space.This doesn't even require *X* be a metric space.